# I need to python code to get sum of some of its k consecutive numbers in a list in python

Tags: python, sum, numbers, addition

#Given array of integers, find the sum of some of its k consecutive elements.

#Sample Input:
#inputArray = [2, 3, 5, 1, 6] and k = 2

```
 #Sample Output:
 #arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k) = 8

 #Explaination:
 #All possible sums of 2 consecutive elements are:

 #2 + 3 = 5;
 #3 + 5 = 8;
 #5 + 1 = 6;
 #1 + 6 = 7.
 #Thus, the answer is 8`
```

Comment: Why is the answer 8?  Are you looking to return the highest sum of the 2 consecutive elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear but assuming you need a function to return the sum of the highest pair of numbers in your list:

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    groups = (inputArray[pos:pos + k] for pos in range(0, len(inputArray), 1)) # iterate through array creating groups of k length
    highest_value = 0 # start highest value at 0
    for group in groups: # iterate through groups
        if len(group) == k and sum(group) > highest_value: # if group is 2 numbers and value is higher than previous value
            highest_value = sum(group) # make new value highest
    return highest_value

inputArray = [2, 3, 5, 1, 6]

print(arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, 2))
  #8
```